# SED basic substitutoin is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, sed

I am on ubuntu 12.04.
Following expression:

```
echo abcd123 | sed 's/\([a-z]*\).*/\1/'
```

is supposed to get result as "abcd". But I am getting "abcd123".
WHY??

Using following site as SED tutorial:
[SED tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-13)

Comment: The expression you typed above should indeed work (and does work for me on my shell).  Try `/bin/sed` instead of just `sed` (in case `sed` is aliased to something weird on your system)?

Comment: Yes. /bin/sed works. Thanks for the quick comment dg99. +1

Comment: Now I'm curious what `sed` is pointing to on your machine!  Could you run `type sed` and paste what it returns?

Comment: sorry dg99. I was working on a project.I just did a type sed and shows "/bin/sed". But I shutdown my computer last time and I can't recreate the same error. It's working fine now and I have been using SED extensively now. Its a great tool. Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your sed command looks fine. I just checked your posted snippet on my own Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS box and it worked perfectly.  Sed is one of those tools that has been around *forever*, so it is unlikely (though certainly not impossible) that 12.04 has a broken sed.  Very strange...

Comment: "I have no answer" is not really an answer.  Perhaps use the Comment function to ask for more information from OP.

Comment: I cannot comment yet (see rep points).  I was simply pointing out that, as presented, his sed command was correct.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  I forgot about the rep limit thing. :(